# Can i extract from my iPhone browser the history older than 8 days ago?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, browser-history

It looks like that the data older than 7 days are automatically wiped from the iphone.

What's the database that stores that data, in case one exist, so that by jailbreaking my iphone i can have direct access to it and hopefully, extract the data i need?

If i did this yesterday, i would not have had this problem... :(

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `var/mobile/Library/Safari/History.plist`. Try looking in that file, but I'm pretty sure Safari itself will only store the most recent seven days of data in that file, though. You'd have to make a tweak that modified Safari to extended that time frame.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Ecamm's [PhoneView](http://ecamm.com/phoneview), it can backup iPhone browser history as well as texts, voicemails, and calls.

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried that and it displays the same things as of the iPhone history interface.

Comment: Well yes, it does. Why exactly do you need your old history?

Comment: I should have visited a linkedin page of a google employe i need to contact... lol :)